# Write `"T1", "T2", ... "T1000"` as factor

Tags: r, character

Command

```
factor(rep(c("T1", "T2", "T3","T4", "T5", "T6","T7", "T8",
         "T9"), each = 1))
```

produces the following output:

```
[1] T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9
Levels: T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9
```

I would like to add other cases, until reaching `T1000` or more. My solution does not work for high values because I should write by hand `"T1", "T2", ... "T1000"`!

Comment: try: `factor(paste("T",1:1000, sep = ""))`

Comment: If you want it to work with higher numbers, you'll need to set the `levels=` explicitly. For example if the values are already in order `x <- paste0("T", 1:20); factor(x, levels=unique(x))` or functions like `gtools::mixedsort` can also sort them in a way you might expect: `factor(x, levels=unique(gtools::mixedsort(x))`

Comment: Thank you! These solutions work perfectly!